# Variance of number of married couples sitting together around a table

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The question: 10 married couples are being sat around a (round) table.

Denote $Y$ - the random variable that equals the number of women sitting next to their husbands. Calculate $V(Y)$.

I tried figuring what is the probabilty that $i$ couples will sit next to each other, but I think this way requires the inclusion and exclusion principle, which I'm pretty sure unnecessary here.

I also tried marking $Y = Y_1 + Y_2 + ... + Y_{10}$ (Where $Y_i$ is 1 if the i-th couple sit next to one another, and 0 otherwise). But this brought up some trouble as well.

I guess I'm stuck more with the combinatorics part of the question, I was hoping you could help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: I think indicator variables work better.  To get the variance, you'll have to compute both $E[Y]$ and $E[Y^2]$.  For the latter you'll need to work with terms of the form $E[Y_iY_j]$, but that's not that difficult.

Comment: It gets hard since when calculation $P(Y_i = 1)$ I can't assume anything on the couples 1,2...,i-1, so there are some problematic spots there.

Comment: Why?  There are two slots next to, say, wife $i$ and there are $19$ empty slots altogether.  Thus the probability that her husband is next to her is $\frac 2{19}$.

Comment: This works only for the first couple, I think. How about the 2nd couple?

Comment: Are you familiar with the use of indicator variables, and Linearity of expectation?  The whole point is that you don't need to worry about the dependence of the variables.

Comment: I can't see why their dependency can be omitted here, it's clearly important because when I denoted them with 1...10 they now have an order? Could you clarify?

Comment: Please read up on [Linearity of Expectation](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linearity-of-expectation/).  The most important feature is that you can ignore dependency.

Comment: @lulu I see, so I can just say something like $P(Y_i = 1) = 2/(n-2i-1)$, and then $E(Y)$ is the sum of those? (no idea how to calculate this sum, really)

Comment: I don't understand.  What's $n$?  And why would you imagine that $P(Y_i=1)$ depends on $i$?  Isn't it clear that $P(Y_i=1)$ is independent of $i$?

Comment: I see now. So it's simply a sum of 10 times $2/19$ and therefore $20/19$. Thanks alot!

Comment: That's the expected number, yes.  Now, variance is more difficult (but still not terrible).  To do it, use the fact that Var$(Y)=E\left[Y^2\right]-E[Y]^2$.  Where, as usual, $E$ denotes expectation.

Comment: Note:  When you deal with terms like $E[Y_1Y_2]$ then you will have to consider dependence since now you need to compute the probability that both of those couples are seated next to each other.

Comment: @lulu I sadly can't get it done. Could you spare some time writing it for me? I have a test tomorrow so I don't have enough time to sit down and figure it out. I'll also be able to mark this question as answered.

Comment: Okay never mind I figured it out. Feel free if you want to write it anyway because I'm still not 100% sure. Thanks alot for the help.